# How do I prevent customer to log in until their account has been activated by the admin

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

After new customer registration, the customer account should be approved by the admin and then a customer can log into their account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one plugin for customer approval on Github [customer activation](https://github.com/Vinai/customer-activation)

And copy files to your project.

plugins contain the folder 'app'
and subfolders as code, etc, locale
place all files to appropriate folders

after installation, you will see customer activation tab at the backend under

> system->Configuration->customer configuration

you need to do setting there as you want

Comment: You have posted the wrong answer if you question is about Magento 2.Vinai module module is related with magento 1.

Comment: By mistake I added that

Comment: the tag says magento-1.9 so this seems like an appropriate answer